# Getting file from S3 and copying to stream is taking ages

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get a 3MB file from a S3 bucket and copying it to a `MemoryStream` because I will need to check what is inside this file at a later point. However, when `CopyToAsync` gets called, it takes at least 1 minute to complete.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
using var s3Object = await _client.GetObjectAsync(getRequest);

var ms = new MemoryStream();

// taking ages
await s3Object.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(ms);

return ms;
```

I tried to use the transfer utility to open the stream or download the file but it takes roughly the same amount of time.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different approach?

From my understanding the `s3Object` variable is receiving metadata about the s3 object + the beginning of the stream of the mentioned file. So when `CopyToAsync gets called` it actually "downloads" the complete file.

The file looks something like this:

```
DEPT    .M                                      :1     Index curve
GR      .GAPI                                   :2     L05-07
DT      .US/F                                   :3     L05-07
RHOB    .G/C3                                   :4     L05-07
DRHO    .G/C3                                   :5     L05-07
NPHI    .V/V                                    :6     L05-07
~Ascii Log Data
      63.1000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000
      63.2000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000
      63.3000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000
      63.4000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000
      63.5000     11.094475   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000
      63.6000     11.473166   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000
      63.7000     12.066418   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000
      63.8000     12.302490   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000
      63.9000     12.272800   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000
      64.0000     11.762026   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000
      64.1000     10.414513   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000
      64.2000      9.588345   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000   -999.250000
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How long does a download of that same object take via the awscli? How far are are you from the S3 region you are downloading from?

Comment: hi @jarmod, I just tried via cli and it took the same amount of time. I'm in Alberta, Canada and the bucket is at us-east-1. Could this be just a network issue or distance to the bucket issue?

Comment: The US West (Oregon) region would certainly be closer to you and may be worth a test but I'm surprised it takes 1 minute to download a 3MB file from within the same continent. From West coast to East coast USA, for example, it's sub-5 seconds. From India to East coast USA, I also see comfortably sub-10 seconds for a 3MB file. Perhaps worth investigating what's going on with your networking.

Comment: I just tested downloading via cli in another machine and it took 1-2 seconds. So it should be my network adapter or some configuration, idk

Comment: Wow, interested to know what's happening there on the bad machine if you get to the root cause.

Comment: The problem was the ethernet cable, I just switched to another one (Cat5e) and it's working fine now. ~1s to get a response and stream the file. I just don't know if the old cable is broken or it's just too old and has speed limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a problem with the ethernet cable. I don't know what's the problem with it but after switching to a new one it's working fine and fast enough, ~1s to get a response, stream and return.